# How can a PhoneGap plugin change the menu on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, menu, phonegap-plugins

I've written a PhoneGap plugin for Android that gets called from the browser on various events, and I'd like it to affect what menu items are shown when the Menu button is pressed. For example, I'd like to disable a certain event, or add certain items. Following the directions [on the Android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu), I know I need to override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to dynamically change the menu items.

Currently, my solution involves writing a file in the plugin, and then parsing that file in onPrepareOptionsMenu. Is there a better way of doing this? And is there any way to get a handle to the main `Activity` from the plugin?

edit: One other way I've just done is to use a public static variable in the main Activity class that I access from the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the SharedPreferences (`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`) to exchange data between plugin and activity. Although it may not suite your situation completely but here is the way I used it.

Plugin1.java

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);

        // Set the preference data based on plugin call
        counter++;
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.ctx.getApplicationContext()).edit().putInt("counter", counter).commit();

        return result;
}
```

AppActivity.java

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        int counter = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()).getInt("counter", 0);
        Log.i("App", "counter value - " + counter);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In my case the shared preferences did the job as it persists the data. You can look into other options [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Right, so I'm currently using the InternalStorage -- why did you go with SharedPreferences instead, out of curiosity?

Comment: I used the shared preferences earlier to maintains application level settings and found it very easy use so that all the activities and background processes has access to same data. I have used files and database also but found preferences straight forward for limited data